# Duplicate rows using multiple Doctrine instances

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following piece of code to import certain Posts into my database. It checks if a post already exists. If this is not the case, it will create a new one.

This script is running in a cron job. However, sometimes it has to be ran manually as well. It can happen that two instances of this script are running simultaniously. When this happens, duplicate records are made. I cannot see why this would be possible.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $entity = new Post();
    $entity
        ->setName($post->name)
        ->setGender($post->gender())
        ->setDate(new \DateTime())
    ;

    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $checkEntity = $em->getRepository('SampleBundle:Post')->findOneBy(array(
        'name' => $post->name
    ));

    if (!$checkEntity) {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Could someone shed a little light on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Simplest solution is prevents same command runs simultaneously.
You could use https://github.com/ffreitas-br/command-lock-bundle

2) You can just catch exception in foreach:

```
$em->persist($entity);

try {
    $em->flush();
} catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    // Detach object to prevent exception with same entity on next flush() call.
    $em->detach($entity);
}
```

If you need save only one entity instance:

```
$em->persist($entity);

try {
    $em->flush($entity);
} catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    // Nothing.
}
```

3) If you want get performance benefits of running two commands parallel think about message queue.
https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle

Producer:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
     $producer->produce(new Message($user['name']));
}
```

Consumer:

```
$name = $message->getName();

$entity = new Post();
$entity
    ->setName($name)
;

$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: In case i use the `UniqueConstraintViolationException` should I make any adjustments to my entity?